# Java - recursive string parsing with hash functions

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, recursion, hash

Assume there's a

```
String str = "sha256(12345sha256(abc)6789sha256(abc))abcdef";
```

How can I recursively hash everything in that String that is between `sha256(` and `)` ? I think about regular expressions but I'm not sure it's the best tool in this situation. What I want to - first of all inner value are hashing, then outer.

I need to do this thing only with `sha256()`, but I think anser to this question with assuming that there're another hash functions (`md5()`, `sha1()` ...) could be helpful for the community.

Thanks

Comment: You can't parse nested syntax with regular expressions, by definition.

Comment: Why not to use Regex just to check if there is and sha256 hash in the current string ? I suggest to use regex to control recursion.

Comment: That's some strange string you have here... Using grappa it's possible, but where do you get that string from in the first place?

Comment: @fge I need to develope some kind of primitive language to operate string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstract class HashFunction{
        public abstract String hash(String in);
    }

class SHA256 extends HashFunction{
    public String hash(String in){
        //replace with a hashfunction
        return "h<" + in + ">";
    }
}

String str = "sha256(12345sha256(abc)6789sha256(abc))abcdef";

//map all available functions to their names
HashMap<String , HashFunction> functions = new HashMap<>();
functions.put("sha256" , new SHA256());

//create a list with the functionNames (not necassary, but simplifies a lot)
ArrayList<String> functionNames = new ArrayList<>();
functionNames.addAll(functions.keySet());

boolean functionFound = false;
do{//as long as functioncalls can be found proceed
    int currentIndex = 0;
    functionFound = false;

    //search for all opening brackets in the function
    while((currentIndex = str.indexOf('(' , currentIndex)) != -1){
        int closeBracket = str.indexOf(')' , currentIndex + 1);
        int openBracket = str.indexOf('(' , currentIndex + 1);

        if(closeBracket == -1 && openBracket > closeBracket)
            throw new Exception("Invalid syntax - missing bracket");
            //should be replaced with a more specific exceptiontype
        if(closeBracket < openBracket || openBracket == -1){
            //the next closing bracket is before the next opening bracket -> the string can be used as input
            functionFound = true;

            //search for the functionname matching the one in str at the given position
            final int curInd = currentIndex;
            final String tmpStr = str;
            Stream<String> matches = functionNames.stream().filter(n -> tmpStr.regionMatches(curInd - n.length() , n , 0 , n.length()));
            Object[] tmp = matches.toArray();

            if(tmp.length > 1)
                throw new Exception("multiple matching hashfunctions");
            if(tmp.length == 0)
                throw new Exception("no matching hashfunction");

            String f = (String) tmp[0];
            HashFunction function = functions.get(f);

            String input = str.substring(currentIndex + 1, closeBracket);
            String hash = function.hash(input);

            //replace hashfunction call with hash
            String temp = str.substring(0 , currentIndex - f.length());
            temp += hash;
            temp += str.substring(closeBracket + 1);
            str = temp;

            //continue search at the end of the last replaced function
            currentIndex = currentIndex - f.length() - input.length() + hash.length();
        }else
            //go to the next nested function call
            currentIndex = openBracket - 1;
    }
}while(functionFound);
```

Works like a char (tested).

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "sha256(12345sha256(abc)6789sha256(abc))abcdef";

    System.out.println(recursiveHash(str, str.length()));
}

public static String recursiveHash(String str, int lastSearchedIndex){
    String tmp = str.substring(0, lastSearchedIndex);
    int innerShaIndex = tmp.lastIndexOf("sha256(");

    if(innerShaIndex != -1){
        int bracketIndex = findCloseBracketIndex(str, innerShaIndex+7);
        String innerSha =  str.substring(innerShaIndex+7, bracketIndex);
        String sha256hex = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(innerSha);

        System.out.println(innerSha+"=="+sha256hex);

        str = str.substring(0, innerShaIndex+7)+
                sha256hex+
                str.substring(bracketIndex);
        str = recursiveHash(str, innerShaIndex);
    }

    return str;
}

public static int findCloseBracketIndex(String str, int startFrom){
    int openBracketCount = -1;
    for(int i = startFrom; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == '('){
            if(openBracketCount == -1){
                openBracketCount = 1;
            }else{
                openBracketCount++;
            }
        }else if(str.charAt(i) == ')'){
            openBracketCount--;
            if(openBracketCount <= -1){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

Comment: result is sha256(debab3eaea45aa04c749946db952536b8c90213fe9d0d4cd9d066f8ae18aead0)abcdef

Answer (score 0):

To find the substrings that you want to hash, i would indeed suggest regex. Try recursively replacing any matches to the following regex:

```
sha256\([^\(\)]*\)
```

(this looks for substrings `sha256(...)` where `...` does not contain any further brackets.)

To include further hashfunctions, i would suggest to add a new regex for each of those and replace the matches with the proper hashvalue inside your recursion.